# Is selling something at a large profit ona'ah (wronging another)?

Tags: transactions, gezel-stealing

What would sources say about the following scenario: let’s say you buy a pen for about $20 and two erasers for $5 each, equaling $30 in total. The person who bought these things sells them for $40, making a $10 profit.

Would sources consider this onaah?

What if I would sell the item for $50?

Comment: A business has overhead such as renting a location, workers, taxes, etc. That is also part of the cost of an item.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Maaser_Sheni.4.2 assumes this

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52858/whats-the-maximum-allowed-profit-that-i-can-make/52860?r=SearchResults#52860

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the [laws of *ona'ah*](https://businesshalacha.com/en/folder-money-matters/unfair-pricing) (unfair pricing) based on the gemara in [Baba Batra 90a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.90a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> And one who profits from his sales may not profit by more than
>   one-sixth.

However,

- the reference price for the calculation is the **fair market price**, in some cases this can be regulated (e.g., for basic food staples), otherwise the price which applies is "any price that the majority of sellers would consider a marketable price" (see [here](https://businesshalacha.com/en/folder-money-matters/unfair-pricing), #2)
- a retailer who sells piece by piece is **compensated for his effort and all his expenses**, and may profit a further sixth above this sum (from [here](https://www.jlaw.com/Articles/price_wage_levels.html), B4, based on [Shulchan Aruch CM 231:20](http://a%20retailer%20who%20sells%20piece%20by%20piece%20is%20compensated%20for%20his%20effort%20and%20all%20his%20expenses,%20and%20may%20profit%20a%20further%20sixth%20above%20this%20sum))
- it is also possible the law only applies to essential items

**So a markup of 33% is completely fine in regard to these laws, as fair compensation for the expenses involved.** Indeed a 2x markup is considered standard in many areas of retail as compensation for rental of sales space, salespeople and other costs.

Comment: This answer mistakenly confuses Ona'ah (overcharging), which appears in Bava Metzia Perek HaZahav and CM 227, with profiteering (ein mistakerin yoter mishetut), which appears in Bava Batra and CM 231. It is therefore incorrect to claim one may overcharge 33%.